# is there a better way to render div boxes in javascript/jquery? Im following this method but i get a lot of errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Try:

```js
    function render_my_div(){
        var div_content = `<div class="firstDiv"><div id="close"></div><div class="secondDiv">
        <p>Test Div</p></div></div>
        `;
        $("#render").html(div_content);
    }
    $('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
        $(".firstDiv").remove();
        $("#div_script").remove();
    }
```

And the HTML:

```html
    <button id="myBtn">Button</button>
    <div id="render"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
const background,color,text;
$(".firstDiv").resizable().draggable();
</script>
```

This seems to be working fine @Mahmoud-Mostafa. But im using jquery UI so that i can implement drag and resize
This dosen't seem to be working at all :(...

PS: I'm sorry if i have not edited/updated my question properly as im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Move the javascript div content outside and render only the div

Comment: What is the point of including that `<script>` fragment when you add the elements? That's what's causing the problem.

Comment: You don't seem to use JavaScript for anything useful in this case. Can't you simply render everything inside a div which has display:none? And then set display: block when button is clicked?

Comment: how you using `const background,color,text;` ? Please update your question for it.

Comment: @zeus your code having problem, if use click `myBtn` multiple time, it will create invalid html. ( id should be unique on page ). this will not work on Safari Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function render_my_div(){
    var div_content = `<div class="firstDiv"><div id="close"></div><div class="secondDiv">
    <p>Test Div</p></div></div>
    `;
    $("#render").html(div_content);
}
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(".firstDiv").remove();
    $("#div_script").remove();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
<div id="render"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">const background,color,text;</script>
```

Comment: This code will have exactly the same problem as the code the OP included.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem!

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
  render_my_div();
  $('head').append('<script id="div_interaction" type="text/javascript">$(".firstDiv").resizable().draggable();</script>');

});
```